# how to pass last occarance in my ordinal=all when i don't know how much occurances is there in my dropdown list?

Tags: c, loadrunner

actually i have a districts in my first drop-down list, i have to select that randomly by each user. now after district selection i have one more drop-down list with mandal divisions. there i don't know how many mandals are there for every district selected by each user. so in that mandal division i have to select last value of drop-down occurrences. so for example: 1st user selected chittoor district there 66 mandals available but i must have to select last one 66th mandal. 2nd user selected Vijayawada there 50 mandals available but i must have to select last one 50th mandal.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and show the corresponding code, reduced to a complete minimal example. Where you don't know how to implement it, write comments about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sudhakar.

When you user capture a parameter called "PARAMETER" with ordinal=all, Loadrunner creates one parameter per ocurrence, called PARAMETER_1, PARAMETER_2... and a parameter called PARAMETER_count, which contains the number of ocurrences found.
All you have to do is to read the value from that PARAMETER_count and to take the parameter in the place of this value.
For example, if PARAMETER_count = 5, then the last ocurrence is saved in PARAMETER_5.

You can do this;

```
    int i;
    char buff[64];
    i = atoi(lr_eval_string("{PARAM_count}"));
    sprintf(buff,"{PARAM_%d}",i);
    lr_log_message("%s",lr_eval_string(buff));
```

You can change the lr_log_message for lr_save_string, for example, and save it in another parameter.

BR,

Carlos.

Comment: Thanks Carlos,   If I want to take before value of last occurrence. How to write that.

Comment: Well, you only have to do "i-1", checking if i > 1 first:

    int i;
    char buff[64];
    i = atoi(lr_eval_string("{PARAM_count}"));
    if (i > 1)
        sprintf(buff,"{PARAM_%d}", i-1);
        lr_log_message("%s",lr_eval_string(buff));

You can user the function lr_paramarr_idx instead using sprintf and a the buffer string variable "buf":

    int i;
    i = atoi(lr_eval_string("{PARAM_count}"));
    if (i > 1)
       lr_paramarr_idx("BEFORE_VALUE",i-1); 
       lr_log_message("%s",lr_eval_string("{BEFORE_VALUE}"));